# Mostrar variable de tipo fecha en un Entry en Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Estoy empezando a programar con Python, y tengo un problema quizás muy sencillo, tengo una variable tipo `TIMESTAMP` en Sqlite 3, trato de visualizarla en un frame y no aparece.

No me da error, simplemente no aparece. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Acá creo un campo tipo `FECHAINT TIMESTAMP`, con el fin de guardar fechas:

```
        micursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE DATOSUSUARIOS (
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        NOMBRE1 VARCHAR(30),
        NOMBRE2 VARCHAR(30),
        APELLIDO1 VARCHAR(10),
        APELLIDO2 VARCHAR(10),
        SEXO VARCHAR(1),
        FECHAINT TIMESTAMP,
        DIAS INTEGER)
        ''')
    messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "BBDD ESCUELA ha sido creada con exito")
```

---

Aquí hago la consulta para visualizar los datos incluyendo la fecha:

```
for BBDDEscuela in elUsuario:
        miID.set(BBDDEscuela[0])
        miNombre1.set(BBDDEscuela[1])
        miNombre2.set(BBDDEscuela[2])
        miApellido1.set(BBDDEscuela[3])
        miApellido2.set(BBDDEscuela[4])
        miSexo.set(BBDDEscuela[5])
        miFecha=(BBDDEscuela[6])
        miDias.set(BBDDEscuela[7])
```

---

Aquí tengo el *entry* para visualizar la fecha, pero no aparece en pantalla:

```
cuadroFecha=Entry(miFrame1, textvariable=miFecha.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
cuadroFecha.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10)

cuadroDias=Entry(miFrame1, width=30, textvariable=miDias, state=DISABLED)
cuadroDias.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes usar `strftime` en un string, ya que `miFecha` es un string, si haces `type(miFecha)` lo podrás observar, puedes usar el módulo `datetime`

```
from datetime import datetime

#d es ahora un objeto datetime
d = datetime.strptime(miFecha, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

#Ahora ya puedes usar strftime en el Entry()
cuadroFecha=Entry(miFrame1, textvariable=d.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Comment: Gracias, cuando colo el set me aparece este error:                                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Proyecto2\Escuela.py", line 72, in leer
    miFecha.set(BBDDEscuela[6])
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'set'

Comment: Hola, perdón por la tardanza, he modificado mi respuesta para dar solución a tú problema.

Comment: Hola he modificado el programa pero me aparece un nuevo error:   
Exception in Tkinter callback  return self.func(*args)
 d=datetime.strptime(miFecha, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
 , line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\Juan Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'